# How can I solve this error? "Error occurred during a cryptographic operation."

Tags: .net

I am having this error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred
>   during a cryptographic operation.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic
>   operation.]
>   System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2
>   func, Byte[] input) +115
>   System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.Protect(Byte[]
>   clearData) +59    System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Object
>   stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +495
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter2.Serialize(Object
>   state, Purpose purpose) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Util.SerializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter,
>   Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +40
>   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Save() +106
>   System.Web.UI.Page.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(Object state) +108
>   System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState() +659
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1225

so I googled it and found this page.

http://www.orcsweb.com/articles/generate-aspnet-machine-key/

I generate machinekey and add the machine key in my Web.config

```
<machineKey validationKey='8D501322497B9D48BF95BA563F9CF801C24775BBAB1A8A072907E2094129E8F415C9EC05489276DB9BB250BFF739EFA2FF828D2D15304546B5C41C7A024B8B4A' decryptionKey='9E98043678E2D8768E20DA3F556418832A901C5D23AA1810' validation='SHA1'/>
```

but still causing error. how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to Decrypt AUTH tokens from another website, make sure the machineKey element contains compatibilityMode="Framework45" element. For older .NET applications sometimes it should be set to "Framework20SP1". Whichever setting you use, it should be the same in both sites.